# GCP - Cloud Client Library not recognizing impersonated account

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, pom.xml

I'm having trouble when trying to make GCP Client Library identify the permissions of a impersonated service account to access Services like Storage and Logging in my Java Maven project. In cloud Run it works fine, but locally, trying --impersonate-service-account doesn't.

I had to use the first version of library because of the framework I'm using, this is my pom.xml

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
           </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and the cloud dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My service account, has the following permissions and roles:

- Environment and Storage Object Administrator
- Editor
- Logging Admin
- Logs Bucket Writer
- Cloud Run Admin
- Secret Manager Secret Accessor

Then, I do the following:

```
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<account-service-email@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com>
```

And try to access a file in the bucket:

```java
private static Storage getStorage() {
     return StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
}

public static File getFile(String filepath) {
    File f = null;
    try {
        f = File.createTempFile(filepath, "");
        Storage storage = GcpStorageService.getStorage();
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, filepath)).build();
        Blob blob = storage.get(blobInfo.getBlobId());
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(f, blob.getContent());
    }catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return f;
}
```

The problem is when I do that, I receive the following message:

```java
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

and:

```java
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
}
```

It seems that the library doesn't recognize the impersonated account, I'm wondering if this could be happening because of the library version, because in another (newer) project I have the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.29.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

and it works fine. Does anyone had a similar issue? I couldn't find a similar case, maybe because of the version of dependency manager.
By the way, this error only occurs when running locally, when I deploy the service to Cloud Run through Cloud Build, using the same impersonated account service, it works fine in a Cloud Run instance. I really don't know what could be happening.

Comment: Are you sure to have the latest version and no conflict?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere You mean the latest version of libraries-bom? If so, it's actually the first version 1.0.0, we had to do so, because other versions would conflict with Guava, and other Guava versions would conflict with our core framework, so we had to use the artifactId libraries-bom version 1.0.0

Comment: They key item is `Anonymous caller`. That means your code is not using credentials for authorization. I seldom work with Java, but that problem means you are setting up the Cloud Storage client incorrectly or if using ADC, the environment is not setup correctly. Note: if you are using an old version of the SDK, the impersonation feature might not be supported.